# Serialization of ArrayList exception

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, ioexception, notserializableexception

I tried to serialize an ArrayList

```
public void writeOnFile(String filePath, ArrayList<Utente> listaUtenti) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream writer=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        writer.writeObject(listaUtenti);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Ha scritto");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File da scrivere non trovato");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problemi di IO nella scrittura");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

also tried

```
public void writeOnFile(String filePath, ArrayList listaUtenti) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream writer=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
        writer.writeObject(listaUtenti);
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Ha scritto");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File da scrivere non trovato");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problemi di IO nella scrittura");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I red that ArrayList is serializable on a lot of sites and also on the documentation of ArrayList as it is a primitive but i still get this exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.UserImpl
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at stewan.Commands.writeOnFile(Commands.java:76)
    at stewan.Commands.onGuildMemberJoin(Commands.java:153)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:551)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:64)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:148)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.GuildMemberAddHandler.handleInternally(GuildMemberAddHandler.java:49)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:37)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:839)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:738)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:717)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:877)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:368)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:270)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:749)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

A tried also to make that class serializable 
`public class Utente implements Serializable`

and also the class contained in that class
`public class Character implements Serializable`

even if there should be no relation.

I also need to read the file and and allocate it to `utenti`, it gives the same exception so theoretically by finding a solution to solve the write method it should also work for read method.

The final file has extension .ser, tried with .bin but same thing.

I also tried to write and read an empty ( new ArrayList() ) and like so it gives no exception, only when there are elements in the ArrayList and it is not empty.

Comment: The exception message says that the problem is that your `UserImpl` class is not serializable.  Either it doesn't implement `Serializable` or it extends a base class that isn't serializable, or it has a (non-transient) field that is not serializable.

Comment: @StephenC (Extending a base class that doesn't implement `Serializable` isn't a problem so long as it has an accessible no-arg constructor.)

Comment: I know.  But the OP hasn't show us the class ...

Comment: I found the where was the problem, thx @Stephen C

Comment: @StefanDoroftei So what was the problem?